# Blocked Compressed Row Storage format of Sparse Matrix

Tags: c, sparse-matrix

I'm writing a program that will convert a sparse matrix to Blocked Compressed Row Storage [BCRS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YR3kK.png).

I know how to acquire Rowptr, Colind(although not in the code) and A_f.

Code:

```
    p = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        row_ptr[++p] = (row_ptr[p - 1] + count_blocks(A, i, n));
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (A[i][j]) {
                A_f[k] = A[i][j];
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
```

The function I use above returns the number of blocks there are in a row:

```
int count_blocks(int matrix[100][100], int row_idx, int n) {
int i;
int block_count = 0;

for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    if (matrix[row_idx][i]) { 
        if (!matrix[row_idx][i + 1])
            block_count++;
        else if (matrix[row_idx][i + 1] && i == n - 2)
            block_count++;
    }
    else if (!matrix[row_idx][i] && i == n - 2) {
        if (matrix[row_idx][i + 1])
            block_count++;
        break;
    }
}
return block_count;
```

But I got stuck at acquiring Nzptr. How do I calculate that?

Code's a  bit redundant, I know.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that computes `nzptr` given a matrix of size 5x5. It returns the number of items in `nzptr`. It also computes indices with C style indexing.

```
int computeNzptr(double matrix[5][5], int nzptr[])
{
   int isNewBlock = 1;
   int nzIndex = 0;
   int nonZeroCount = 0;
   int i = 0;
   int j = 0;
   for ( i = 0; i < 5; ++i )
   {
      for ( j = 0; j < 5; ++j )
      {
         if ( matrix[i][j] != 0.0 )
         {
            ++nonZeroCount;
            if ( isNewBlock )
            {
               isNewBlock = 0;
               nzptr[nzIndex++] = nonZeroCount-1;
            }
         }
         else
         {
            isNewBlock = 1;
         }
      }
   }
   return nzIndex;
}
```

**PS**

In the reference image, the descriptions and the answers don't match. When you have a 5x5 matrix, which is the same as the matrix in the posted image,

```
double matrix[5][5] =
{
   {5.0, 1.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0},
   {0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 3.0},
   {0.0, 2.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0},
   {0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 0.0},
   {0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0}
};
```

The output as per the description should be:

```
0 3 4 6 8 10 11
```

This is different from the output in the reference.

I am assuming that the description in the reference document is correct and the output is incorrect.

Comment: If I understood right, Nzptr[i + 1] - Nzptr[i] = length of a block. Since in the matrix there are 7 blocks, Nzptr should be as follows:
`0 3 4 6 8 10 11 12`

Comment: @Ascent, the description says: *Nzptr (of length the number of blocks)*. There are 7 blocks in the above `matrix`. I can see why the last number will be useful in `nzptr`, but it's superfluous.  It is same as the number of elements in `Af`.

Comment: @R Sahu, but the algorithm for multiplication uses Nzptr as ranges, if we avoid the last number stuff will go wrong.. And I can't find why it doesn't contain 12 in the end.

Comment: Dear @RSahu could you give me more information about this method ? I wrote a C++ class with the constructor that works fine but I have not information about the algorithm for moltiplication ?